# Migrando do svn para git: tags ganham um '@' com número ao final da tag. O que pode ser?

Tags: git

Estou com uma dúvida. Fiz o clone do projeto com `git svn clone`. Utilizei o `git remote add +url` para adicionar o repositório remoto. Quando estou fazendo o `git push --tags` para o git as tags estão indo em um formato diferente do svn. Por exemplo:

- No SVN: `tag_all_1.0.0.`
- No GIT (migrado): `tag_all_1.0.0@431`

Alguém sabe o que pode ser isso?

Comment: Oi. No meu projeto utilizei o subgit [link](https://www.smartsvn.com/subgit/) e não enfrentei esta dificuldade, todas as tags foram migradas corretamente. Vale o teste?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a [explicação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356901/git-svn-clone-spurious-branches) para [isto ocorrer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) com as tags seja a mesma com as branches: o Git Svn não foi capaz de encontrar um commit "pai" para o primeiro commit da branch SVN para que ele possa conectar a branch com o histórico das outras branches.

Isto ocorre porque o SVN permite que uma branch possa ser criada de um diretório qualquer que não seja necessariamente uma branch (ou trunk) dentro do SVN. Por exemplo, copiando o diretório `/trunk/foo` para `/branches/bar` ao invés de copiar a partir do `/trunk` dará origem a esta branch.

O formato no qual ele cria a branch (ou tag) é:

```
<branchname>@<SVN-Revisão>
```

Agora, explicar a origem desta revisão e por que o Git toma esta decisão é mais [complicada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13291121/2387977). Confesso que li e não entendi muito bem e, para não simplesmente traduzir o que está dito lá, deixo o [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) para ler a explicação da documentação. Acredito que isto já ajude, pois não é tão simples buscar por informações deste problema no Google :).

Isto acontece com `tag` também porque no SVN não há muita diferença entre branch e tag: ambos são criados por meio de cópia de diretórios. O Git Svn então reflete o mesmo comportamento para ambas.

## Como evitar esta situação

Na clonagem do repositório, esta criação de branch/tag com o sinal de arroba (`@`) pode ser evitado com o parâmetro `--no-follow-branches`.